# using regualr expression in mysql to select specific rows

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select a small set of records that match a patten I have a series of numbers in each row such as

1
2
3
some of them have sub numbers
3.1
3.2
4
5

I can select only the whole numbers using

```
REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

I can select all rows that have a . in them like 3.1 3.2 etc using

```
REGEXP '[.]{1}'
```

but I can't seem to select for example only sub numbers that start with 3 I've tried

```
REGEXP '[^3.]{1,}'
```

but that returns all records

Ideally I want to return only records that are in the format of 3.1 I would like to define the start number and the dot so 3. then the second part match against the records

I hope this makes sense

Comment: I should add the column with the numbers in is using a float data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `'3\.[0-9]{1,}'` - it matched.

Yours probably fails because of unescaped dot - `.`, which matches every character.
Escape characters with `\`

Answer (score 1):

Format `3.d` where `d` is digit:

```
3\\.[0-9]
```